# Customize alert text in duplicate rules.

Tags: duplicate-management

Alext text in Duplicate Rules : Is it possible to use custom labels for the alert text ?...i need to show the alert in 2 different languages. I tried using custome labels it is not working ! [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think salesforce will allow you to show two different alert message in single duplicate rule. We can go for trigger to write logic to show different error message while occurring duplicate records.